# Cyclic behaviour within a week and day

Tags: matlab

I have some doubt regrading cyclic behaviour as explained using below example. From FFT magnitude it is very well possible to find the the weekly and daily cycle. But doubt is that how to find the cyclic variation within a week and a day (as highlighted below). Or we need some extra info? I am unable to post picture kindly look for below link for the same.
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-frequency-domain-analysis.html

Thanks for you time!

Analyzing Cyclic Behavior of the Temperature in an Office Building

Consider a set of temperature measurements in an office building during the winter season. Measurements were taken every 30 minutes for about 16.5 weeks. Look at the time domain data with the time axis scaled to weeks. Could there be any periodic behavior on this data?

![enter image description here][2]

It is almost impossible to know if there is any cyclic behavior on the office temperatures by looking at the time-domain signal. However, the cyclic behavior of the temperature becomes evident if we look at its frequency-domain representation.

Obtain the frequency-domain representation of the signal. If you plot the magnitude of the FFT output with a frequency axis scaled to cycles/week, you can see that there are two spectral lines that are clearly larger than any other frequency component. One spectral line lies at 1 cycle/week, the other one lies at 7 cycles/week. This makes sense given that the data comes from a temperature-controlled building on a 7 day calendar. The first spectral line indicates that building temperatures follow a weekly cycle ***with lower temperatures on the weekends and higher temperatures during the week***. The second line indicates that there is also a daily cycle ***with lower temperatures during the night and higher temperatures during the day***.

```
NFFT = length(temp);              % Number of FFT points
F = (0 : 1/NFFT : 1/2-1/NFFT)*Fs; % Frequency vector

TEMP = fft(temp,NFFT);
TEMP(1) = 0; % remove the DC component for better visualization

helperFrequencyAnalysisPlot2(F*60*60*24*7,abs(TEMP(1:NFFT/2)),...
  'Frequency (cycles/week)','Magnitude',[],[],[0 10])
```

![enter image description here][3]

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem! The thing is, that the longer you examine the data, the less accurate the cyclic variations become. Take for example the temperature problem. Let's say that you instead examine the temperature for 1 year. You will then be able to say, that "HEY, one time a week the temperature is lower" or "one time a day the temperature is lower", but you cannot say exactly when it happens. You just know that it is once per day. This can actually be understood by looing at the fourier transform. I short impulse in time gives wideband spectrum and a narrowband frequency gives a long time delay.

The claim that it is on weekends and nights is most likely a conclusion from mathworks, or a result of other investigations. It would possibly be easier to find out the daily variations of the temperature, by looking at a shorter time span, but then the longterm periodic variations would be hard to measure instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is it possible to use the phase information to figure out the variation within a week or a day? Just a guess!

Comment: I am not 100% sure about that, but my guess is that it would give poor results. Fourier analysis is good to use to find periodic behaviours, but there are no real way to say if the occurences will follow the behaviour. This can be seen on the periodogram which in some sense average the frequency components over time. The normal way to go to find periodic variations is to deseasonalize the data. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonality. This does however not stop you from trying it your way.